# Is there a way to adjust the interface to Blender's File Explorer?

Tags: file-browser, mouse

case is: In Blender 3.4 when trying to import a file, the right scroll bar is animated to become wider when hovered, but still this scroll bar is very thin..., so scrolling there is like walking a thin flexible ridge... all the time activating files which are not desired, it is impossible to scroll a list, let alone select the desired file. i can do it only with keyboard navigation.

When the pointer is halfway on the scrollbar, it is already selecting files...

Anybody else experiencing this problem in Blender 3.4 file explorer?

Comment: It seem that you're unhappy with how the scroll bar functions in the file viewer on Windows, but I'm not sure what you're asking for beyond that. Could you please clearify what your question is? Please keep in mind that this is a community-driven Q&A website and not Blender's bug tracker.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports). If you have a question we can answer, please rephrase your post to make it clearer what you are asking